# Is there a way to explicitly specify an alternative location for NLTK's corpora/wordnet?

Tags: python, nltk

I have a script which utilizes NLTK's WordNetLemmatizer, which, in turn, requires corpora/wordnet to be present in a certain location on the user's system. WordNetLemmatizer is imported as follows:

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
```

My script (actually, a pretty hefty program) is compiled into an executable, and I can't expect the end-user to install NLTK components. I'd like to include corpora/wordnet in my program's directory.

Is there a way to get WordNetLemmatizer to look for corpora/wordnet in an explicitly specified location, in particular, in the same directory as the executable file generated from my python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried to add the following line to your script?

```
nltk.path.append('/home/user/some_directory/nltk_data/')
```

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: `nltk.data.path.append` does the trick. Thanks.